# Lighttpd redirect non-www to www

Tags: lighttpd, 301-redirect

I want to redirect all non-www to www on my domain.

But when I use this code provided by some websites, and do a graceful restart of the lighttpd server, my website doesn't function anymore - at all:

```
$HTTP[”host”] =~ “^example\.com” {
    url.redirect = (
        ”^/(.*)$” => “http://www.example.com/$1″
    )
}
```

But when I use the one provided at [lighttpd's wikipedia page](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect), it works, but it redirects everything example.com/ANYTHINGHERE to www.example.com, i.e. example.com/search.php?v=michael is redirected to www.example.com:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$" {
  url.redirect = (
    ".*" => "http://www.%1" 
  )
}
```

I have remembered to include mod_redirect in the config file. Can anyone help me? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are messing with all type of quotation marks. Only `" "`, "programmer’s" quotes, are recognized as quotes in configuration files. You configuration now has curved quotes (”, “) and even Chinese style prime quotation mark (″).

You could try this

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
  url.redirect  = (
    "^/(.*)" => "http://www.example.com/$1",
  )
}
```

Comment: It still redirects me to www.example.com, unfortunately. :-/

Comment: I tried to simplify it a bit more. Tell me if it works. I'm more familiar with Apache's mod_rewrite syntax.

Comment: The simplified version worked! But how come? What difference does it make to have $HTTP["host"] == "example.com" VS. $HTTP["host"] =~ "^example\.com$". What does the ~, ^, \ and $ do?

Comment: `==` is used for string equal match and `=~` for perl style regular expression match. In this case regular expression is not necessary since the case is rather simple. In the regex, `^` states beginning of string and `$` end of string.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help and the explanation! :-)